# Java - Iterate List of Map based on condition

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following json structure

```
{
  "CreateDtTm": "2019-02-06T10:34:06",
  "AcftType": "Event",
  "EqpCd": "73Y",
  "TailNbr": "N26226",
  "docType": "TailClndr",
  "TailActvy": [
    {
      "FlightLeg": {
        "DepDlyMin": "1",
        "TaxiInMin": "0",
        "AccumTm": -99000000,
        "Indicators": {
          "In": "0",
          "ArrRtbl": "0",
          "Cncl": "1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "FlightLeg": {
        "DepDlyMin": "1",
        "TaxiInMin": "0",
        "AccumTm": -99000000,
        "Indicators": {
          "In": "1",
          "ArrRtbl": "0",
          "Cncl": "0"
        }
      }
    }    
  ]
}
```

I need to iterate the map and extract the "FlightLeg" with "Indicators" "IN" as 1. With traditional way I have implemented as shown below-

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> tailActiviyList = (List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>) aircraftRoutingInfoMap
        .get("TailActvy");

for (HashMap<String, Object> flightActivityMap : tailActiviyList) {
    if (flightActivityMap.containsKey("FlightLeg")) {
        HashMap<String, Object> flightLegMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) flightActivityMap.get("FlightLeg");
        HashMap<String, Object> flightIndicators = (HashMap<String, Object>) flightLegMap.get("Indicators");

        if(flightIndicators.get("In").equals("0") && flightIndicators.get("Cncl").equals("0"))
        {
            aircraftRoutingList.add(flightLegMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be implemented using Java Stream.

Comment: Suggestion: Use classes to identify objects

Comment: *"Can this be implemented using Java Stream?"* **Yes.** Now read: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Answer (score 0):

Though conceptually what you're looking from streams is the use of `filter` and `map` :

```
List<Map<String, Object>> aircraftRoutingList = tailActiviyList.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.containsKey("FlightLeg")
                && ((Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) f.get("FlightLeg")).get("Indicators")).get("In").equals("0")
                && ((Map<String, Object>) ((Map<String, Object>) f.get("FlightLeg")).get("Indicators")).get("Cncl").equals("0")
        )
        .map(m -> (Map<String, Object>) m.get("FlightLeg"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Yet, just looking at it, one would at first suggest using classes to model your objects and then further improve the code readability to a greater extent.